# How to include map.php as a source of an img tag

Tags: php, symfony1, file, dictionary

I am displaying a map in my page, in static PHP it is something like `(img src="action/map.php")` as all the code regarding map is in `map.php`.

In Symfony, I am getting confused where to put my `map.php` file and how to include that file as a source of an img tag.

Answer (score 2):

you could get it done with e.g. an action:

```
public function executeShowmap(){
  $this->getResponse()->setHttpHeader('Content-type', 'image/jpeg');
  $this->getResponse()->setContent(file_get_contents($filename));
  return sfView::NONE;
}
```

and in the view:

```
img src="<?php echo url_for('module/showmap'); ?>"
```

Comment: Where is filename getting passed through? ;-)

Comment: @jamie, thats only an example… guess he got more logic in map.php. just deliver an image over an action would be … stupid. ;)